# Atlascopco screw compressor unload abnormal sound

Tags: mechanical-engineering, compressed-air, compressors, maintenance

We are facing an issue in our GA 75 FF model compressor. During the unload time the compressor is making some abnormal noise, but during the load it is working fine.

When the machine is unloaded after 30 seconds the abnormal sound starts. We changed the blow off valve and checked but still it is same. We checked the oil stop valve and check valve also found no issue. Are we missing something here?

Comment: how do you know that the sound is abnormal?